# Why is the type of expression following in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following code in which I represented natural numbers using Peano number.

```
data NaturalF a = ZeroF | SuccF a deriving Functor
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
expressionFix :: Fix NaturalF
expressionFix = Fix $ SuccF $ Fix $ SuccF $ Fix $ SuccF $ Fix ZeroF
```

The type of expressionFix here is Fix NaturalF. However, when I try to use other recursive newtype, the type is the complete expansion of types of the expression.

```
data NaturalF a = ZeroF | SuccF a deriving Functor

newtype OtherType f = OtherType f

expressionOtherType :: OtherType
  (NaturalF
     (OtherType
        (NaturalF (OtherType (NaturalF (OtherType (NaturalF a)))))))
expressionOtherType = OtherType $ SuccF $ OtherType $ SuccF $ OtherType $ SuccF $ OtherType ZeroF
```

Why is it that fix doesn't expand the expression type and ignore the other types in front of it but other recursive types don't?

I tried other recursive functions but they gave the outputs with expansion.

Comment: `OtherType` is not recursive.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If `OtherType` was recursive would the `expressionOtherType` be of type `OtherType NaturalF`? Also could you give me an example of recursive`OtherType` which would fit here? Thanks.

Comment: There is no (single) transformation that takes a non-recursive thing and just tacks on the property of being recursive. If you want to talk about a recursive definition of `OtherType` and what its properties would be, you have to show us this alternative definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how `Fix` works.  The type of the constructor `ZeroF` is:

```
ZeroF :: NaturalF a
```

The type of the constructor `Fix` is:

```
Fix :: f (Fix f) -> Fix f
```

When you write the expression:

```
Fix ZeroF
```

the type variables `a` and `f` are unified to:

```
f ~ NaturalF
a ~ Fix NaturalF
```

giving the specialized constructor types:

```
ZeroF :: NaturalF (Fix NaturalF)
Fix :: NaturalF (Fix NaturalF) -> Fix NaturalF
```

and a final expression type (from the typing rules for normal function application):

```
Fix ZeroF :: Fix NaturalF
```

Similarly, when you apply `SuccF`, which has type:

```
SuccF :: a -> NaturalF a
```

to this expression, this results in the unification:

```
a ~ Fix NaturalF
```

and so the specialized types are:

```
Fix ZeroF :: Fix NaturalF
SuccF :: Fix NaturalF -> NaturalF (Fix NaturalF)
```

and so (again, by the typing rules for normal function application):

```
SuccF $ Fix ZeroF :: NaturalF (Fix NaturalF)
```

Finally, if you apply `Fix` to this, the specialized type of `Fix` is the same as above, namely:

```
Fix :: NaturalF (Fix NaturalF) -> Fix NaturalF
```

which gives the final type (normal function application, again):

```
Fix $ SuccF $ Fix ZeroF :: Fix NaturalF
```

Each further application of `Fix $ SuccF $ ...` maps a `Fix NaturalF` to another `Fix NatrualF`, so the type doesn't change.

In contrast, the type of the `OtherType` constructor is:

```
OtherType :: f -> OtherType f
```

When you apply it to `ZeroF`, you get the types:

```
ZeroF :: NaturalF a     -- `a` does not unify with anything
OtherType :: f -> OtherType f
```

and so:

```
OtherType ZeroF :: OtherType (NaturalF a)
```

When you apply `SuccF` to this, the `a` *still* does not unify, so you have the specialized types:

```
OtherType ZeroF :: OtherType (NaturalF a)
SuccF :: OtherType (NaturalF a) -> NaturalF (OtherType (NaturalF a))
```

giving:

```
SuccF (OtherType ZeroF) :: NaturalF (OtherType (NaturalF a))
```

applying the constructor `OtherType` to this expression specialized `OtherType` to:

```
OtherType :: NaturalF (OtherType (NaturalF a)) -> OtherType (NaturalF (OtherType (NaturalF a)))
```

still without unifying `a` with anything, and the final result is:

```
OtherType (SuccF (OtherType ZeroF)) :: OtherType (NaturalF (OtherType (NaturalF a)))
```

The key difference is that `Fix` -- because of the `Fix f` on the right-hand side of its definition -- forces the unification:

```
a ~ Fix NaturalF
```

at every step.

If you want to construct another type that works exactly like `Fix`, then it's going to look just like `Fix`:

```
data OtherType f = OtherType (f (OtherType f))
```

Alternative recursive types would behave somewhat differently.  For example, the recursive type:

```
data MaybeFix f a = JustFix (f (MaybeFix f a)) | DontFix (f a)
```

can construct things like this:

```
data NaturalF a = ZeroF | SuccF a deriving Functor

foo :: MaybeFix NaturalF String
foo = JustFix $ SuccF $ JustFix $ SuccF $ DontFix $ SuccF "foo"
```

but the key is that it's recursive:  a "call" to the type `MaybeFix f a` appears on the right-hand side of the `data MaybeFix` declaration:

```
data MaybeFix f a = JustFix (f (MaybeFix f a)) | DontFix (f a)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```